# Join two tables where a date is in the other tables date range

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to write a SQL in SSMS to join two tables by an date.

Table A holds the actual date the transaction happened

```
    SELECT  A.Client,
    A.TrnDate,
    FROM    dbo.Transation A

    Client      TrnDate
    00011547    2001-07-17 00:00:00.000
    00011547    2013-07-04 00:00:00.000
    00011547    2013-11-13 00:00:00.000
    00011547    2014-12-14 00:00:00.000
    00011547    2014-12-14 00:00:00.000
```

Table B holds the rates the transactions should cost by the effective from date.

```
     SELECT     B.Client,
        B.Effdate,
        B.Rate
     FROM       dbo.ChargeRate B 

    Client      EffDate                 Rate
    00011547    2008-04-01 00:00:00.000 1223
    00011547    2013-05-28 00:00:00.000 1224
    00011547    2013-10-01 00:00:00.000 1302
    00011547    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 1355
    00011547    2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 1376
    00011547    2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 1397
```

As you can see the transaction date can fall inbetween the effective from periods I would like the joined table to be like the below.

```
    Client      TrnDate                  Rate
    00011547    2001-07-17 00:00:00.000  1223
    00011547    2013-07-04 00:00:00.000  1224
    00011547    2013-11-13 00:00:00.000  1302
    00011547    2014-12-14 00:00:00.000  1397
    00011547    2014-12-14 00:00:00.000  1397
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks you in advance Phil

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easly with the [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) operator

```
select
    [T].[Client],
    [T].[TrnDate],
    [CR].[Rate]
from dbo.Transaction [T]
outer apply (
    select top 1
        [CR].[Rate]
    from dbo.ChargeRate [CR]
    where
        [CR].EffDate <= [TrnDate]
    order by
        [EffDate] DESC
) [CR]
```

Comment: I haven't run this statement, but looking at the data tables this won't turn up the first row in the expected output: `00011547, 2001-07-17 00:00:00.000,   1223`

Comment: @TT. you are correct. it won't. Another apply for those cases would resolve it. But i blame the Data =p

Comment: Thanks for both your help the above apply solution worked a treat but didn't return the first expected output as TT pointed out. I'll take a look at using another apply to fix the issue.

Comment: @PhilGarside The sample data you provided, states that you don't have the Rate at the time the first record was created. Either get the first rate available, or just correct your data so that a "default" rate is applied when NULL or correct your data and avoid the work around for missing data. Good luck =)